# How to use a variable directory name in an expect shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell, variables, expect

I want to call a variable to find the current user ID within an expect shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
set pass "password"
set username [id -un]
spawn scp -r root@serveraddress:/var/scpserver /Users/$username/Library/Songs/song.mp3`
```

Unfortunately this is not working as it gives me the following error

```
Mac:TestDir Matthew$ ./tester.sh 
invalid command name "id"
while executing "id -un"
invoked from within
"set username [id -un]"
(file "./tester.sh" line 3)`
```

The idea behind this is that I can run this script on any computer regardless of what the users username is to assigned to that computer.

Comment: Set up public-key authorization, and you won't need `expect` at all.

Comment: @chepner That's not practical for me to do as I am planning on using this on 50+ computers. That would require me to set each one up individuals. However I believe that indeed this would useful for a smaller scale of devices. Correct me if i am wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id -un` is a system command, not a Tcl command. You should use `exec` to execute any system command.

```
set username [exec id -un]
```

Instead of this way, you can rely on the Tcl's inbuilt `tcl_platform(user)` variable to get the current username.

Comment: Or simply use `$env(USER)`.

Comment: Windows doesn't have `env(USER)`, instead it is `env(USERNAME)`. This is the reason why I used to prefer `tcl_platform(user)`